# Prove the convergence of sequences $x_0> 1, x_{n +1} = \log_2 (1 + x_n), n\geq 0$ and

Tags: sequences-and-series

To show $x_n, y_n$ defined by $$x_0> 1, x_{n +1} = \log_2 (1 + x_n), n\geq 0$$ and $$y_n =\frac{(1+x_1)(1+x_2)...(1+x_n)}{2^n}, n\geq1$$ are converging.

For $x_n$, using inequality $2^x>1+x, x>1$ low evening that $x_n$ is descending and bounded and has limit $1$. For $y_n$ is increasing but we found that we could not prove that it is bounded above and criterion ratio but did not help. 
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already stated, $x_n$ converges to $1$. We have
$$\log_2 y_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\log_2(1+x_k)-n=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}x_k-n$$
Defining $a_n=x_n-1$, we have then
$$\log_2y_n=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}(a_k-1)-n=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}a_k$$
So, to prove that $y_n$ converges, we must show that the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty a_n$ converges. Let's apply the ratio test:
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\log_2(2+a_n)-1}{a_n}=\frac{\ln(2+a_n)-\ln2}{a_n\ln 2}=\frac{\ln (1+\frac{a_n}{2})}{a_n \ln 2}$$
Hence,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{a\rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln (1+\frac{a}{2})}{a \ln 2}=\frac{1}{2\ln 2}=\frac{1}{\ln4}<1,$$
so, the series converges, and so do $y_n$.

Comment: What explains the equality:$$\sum_{k=1}^n\log_2(1+x_k)-n=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}x_k-n?$$

Comment: The fact that $\log_2(1+x_k)=x_{k+1}$. Be careful about the indexes.